# How to solve paymentsAppConfigure error (You do not have permission to access this website)

Tags: shopify

On Shopify, I'm getting paymentsAppConfigure error (You do not have permission to access this website).

```php
$queryArr = [
    'query'     => 'mutation PaymentsAppConfigure($externalHandle: String, $ready: Boolean!) {
            paymentsAppConfigure(externalHandle: $externalHandle, ready: $ready) {
                paymentsAppConfiguration {
                    externalHandle
                    ready
                }
                userErrors{
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
        }',
    'variables' => [
        'externalHandle' => 'API_token_key',
        'ready'          => true
    ]
];

$query = json_encode($queryArr);

$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Shopify-Access-Token:<My_token>', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$err    = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
// echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($err);
print_r($result);
```

This query is giving the following error:

> You do not have permission to access this website

Also, what is the externalHandle API_token_key? I have used the App API key but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your app should have `write_payment_gateways` and `write_payment_sessions` permissions in order to make that call. You need to contact Shopify support to enable these permissions.
Reference: https://shopify.dev/apps/payments/onboarding-a-merchant-payments-apps#permissions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mehar above, you app should have requested permissions.

Below is payload that I'm sending and works as expected, you can try that if you want.

```
{
    "query": "mutation {  paymentsAppConfigure(externalHandle : \"Activation request at 2020-04-09 11:24:14.785868848\" ,ready: true) {   paymentsAppConfiguration {      externalHandle      ready    }    userErrors {    field      message    }  } }",
    "variables": {}
}
```

Below are the header details that I send with the request

```
X-Shopify-Access-Token -> Your token
Content-Type -> application/json
Cookie -> request_method=POST
```